# Regex for the django form field

Tags: python, regex, django, django-forms

I have a form field:

```
web_address = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^DO SOMETHING$', error_messages = {'invalid': _("Not a valid web address.")})
```

I am unable to write a regular expression for the above address. My requirement is to validate the url in the form http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=1234. The id 1234 is a variant but the prior would be constant.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are just two thing to know

1. `?` and `.` are special characters in regex and need escaping
2. checking for digits, either use the predefined class `\d` or define your own `[0-9]` and say at least one `\d+`

so your regex should look something like

```
^http://maps\.google\.com/maps/place\?cid=\d+$
```

If you want to learn more about regexes, [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a good place to start.

To test you regexes you can use online testers like [gskinner.com/RegExr/](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). You can see your regex [here](http://regexr.com?30dgi)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
web_address = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^http\\:\\/\\/maps\\.google\\.com\\/maps\\/place\\?cid\\=\d+'$', error_messages = {'invalid': _("Not a valid web address.")})
```

IE:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('^http\\:\\/\\/maps\\.google\\.com\\/maps\\/place\\?cid\\=\d+',      'http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=1234', re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1251fa8>
```